# how can I obtain the 4 coordinates of an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement this method:

```
//#OnTouchEvent()
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//Coordinates of the touch
int x = (int) event.getX();
int y = (int) event.getY();

switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // Check if the touch is within the coordinates of an image
            if x isBetweenCoordinatesXofTheImage
                 if y isBetweenCoordinatesYofTheImage
                     //DoSomething
            else
                 //DoNothing
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //nothing
    break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    //check if the touch is within the coordinates of an image;
            if x is betweenCoordinatesX of the image
                 y is betweenCoordinatesYofTheImage
                     //DoSomething
            else
                 //DoNothing
    break;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

An ImageView has 4 coorners and I need to know the 4 coordinates (x,y) to do the check before.
The upper left corner has the same X-coordinate as the lower left and upper right will have the same X coordinate to the lower right. for Y coordinates is similar.
My problem is: how I can obtain the 4 coordinates of a ImageView?

THANKS for all!!!

Comment: I know I'm missing something.  x, y, x + width, y + height

Comment: why not a view.ontouchlistener on your imageview?

Comment: I know this method, but I need to do it with the way I indicated. I need to do a match movement between two images. I need to do it pressing the screen and draging my finger to the next image without lifting my finger. If I use your method, the method OnTouchEvent doesn't execute. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small question:
Why not set the ImageView itself a touch listener?
If that's not an options then try:

```
int pos[] = new int[2];
yourImageView.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
```

After you'll call this method the array will contain the upper left coordinate of your view.
To get the other coordinates just use the height and width of the view:

```
yourImageView.getWidth();
yourImageView.getHeight();
```

Make sure those three methods are called only AFTER the view has drawn on the screen - (invoking them in the onCreate will return 0 to all values).

Comment: I don't want to use a touch listener because I need to implement a "match" movement, and I have to press the screen, dragging and lifting my finger off the screen.

Comment: And thanks for last comment, because I have the problem you say. you are my savior hahahaha

Comment: If the answer is good it'll be great if you'll accept it.
If you're having issues like in your last post:

Comment: Your get 0:0 because the view has not yet been drawn. And with this one coordinate + the view's width and height you can get the all four:
(x,y), (x+width, y), (x, y + height), (x + width, y + height)

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL!!!!Yes, I do click to accept the answer, but I can't click and indicate that the answer has been very helpful because I have enough reputation, so sorry. I hope that other people can do because it can be useful for more people.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getLocationOnScreen()
```

and/or

```
getLocationInWindow()
```

on your imageView.